# Allure report embedding trouble

Tags: jenkins-groovy, allure, python-behave

I am creating an Allure report on Jenkins for my Selenium code(Python + behave). Everything works great. Except two things.

---

**1.**  I cannot get it to embed in the email correct

I have the email extension plugin and have tried setting the email content to:

```
${SCRIPT, template="allure-report.groovy"}
```

However, just get a long error in the email content that looks like:

```
Exception raised during template rendering: Cannot invoke method getParameter() on null object java.lang.NullPointerException...
```

**Question:** How to get the allure template embed in email? I have tried [these steps](https://gist.github.com/letsrokk/50a3ffc8ad5af8896ce78e62fe1e8cb5#file-jenkinsfile) but cannot seem to get it. The actual allure report functions fine.

---

**2.** The allure attachments are not allure-attachments folder sticks around

`allure-report / data / attachments`

Then when an email is generated for each build with the attachments it gets the previous builds attachments because they never go away.

**Question:** How to make only current build attachments(PNG,XLSX) embed in an email?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Removed **getParameter()** from the template

Renamed it *new-allure-report.groovy*

Called with `${SCRIPT, template="new-allure-report.groovy"}`